# Gradle build - add module path

Tags: java, gradle, command-line, dependencies, java-module

My question: How do I set a module path for `gradle build`?

I've become comfortable working with Java modules from the command line.  I do a frequent exercise in Powershell which results in these source files.

```
└───src
    ├───appMod
    │   │   module-info.java
    │   │
    │   └───appPack
    │           Entry.java
    │
    └───greetMod
        │   module-info.java
        │
        └───greetPack
                Hello.java
```

#### appMod/module-info

```
module appMod {
    requires greetMod;
}
```

#### appMod/appPack.Entry

```
package appPack;

import greetPack.Hello;

public class Entry {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Hello().sayHello());
    }
}
```

#### greetMod/module-info

```
module greetMod {
    exports greetPack;
}
```

#### greetMod/greetPack.Hello

```
package greetPack;

public class Hello {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Greetings from Hello class!";
    }
}
```

Since the appMod module requires greetMod, I compile and jar greetMod first.

```
javac -d out/greetMod src/greetMod/module-info.java src/greetMod/greetPack/Hello.java;
jar cf lib/greetJar.jar -C out/greetMod .;
```

Then I compile and jar appMod, but as I do so I specify the module path (-p) where the new greetMod jar (greetJar) can be found (in lib).

```
javac -d out/appMod -p lib src/appMod/module-info.java src/appMod/appPack/Entry.java;
jar cfe lib/appJar.jar appPack.Entry -C out/appMod .;
```

I can then run this or jlink it in part by adding a module path.

```
java -p lib -m appMod;
jlink -p lib --add-modules appMod --launcher launch=appMod --output dist;
dist/bin/launch
```

I now want to do this same exercise in Gradle, but I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of setting a module path such as `-p lib`.  I've seen code for [sourceSets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html), and countless variations of [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_types.html), but so far I haven't been able to put together something that works.  I've also read conflicting statements that both say that [Gradle doesn't fully support Java modules](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/), and that [Gradle does support them](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity#command-line-options).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it can be confusing, but it can definitely be done by gradle. You will need to use a multiproject build to have this work. In your top-most `build.gradle`, do this:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.9

    compileJava {
        doFirst {
            options.compilerArgs += [
                    '--module-path', classpath.asPath
            ]
            classpath = files()
        }
    }
}
```

In your `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'module-testing'

include 'src:greetMod'
include 'src:appMod'
```

Everything inside `appMod` should be moved into a folder called `appModSrc`. Do the same for `greetMod` so use `greetModSrc`.

---

### greetMod

Directory structure:

```
├── build.gradle
└── greetModSrc
    ├── greetPack
    │   └── Hello.java
    └── module-info.java
```

#### build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'greetModSrc'
        }
    }
}
```

---

### appMod

Directory structure:

```
├── appModSrc
│   ├── appPack
│   │   └── Entry.java
│   └── module-info.java
└── build.gradle
```

#### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'appModSrc'
        }
    }
}

application {
    mainClassName 'appPack.Entry'
}

jar {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes('ModuleMainClass': mainClassName)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':src:greetMod')
}
```

---

With this setup, you can simply run **`./gradlew :src:appMod:run`:**

```
> Task :src:appMod:run
Greetings from Hello class!
```

You can download the idea project here: https://github.com/MVCE-Superstars/multi-java9-gradle

Answer (score 4):

Since [Gradle 6.4](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/release-notes.html) you can used set the [`inferModulePath`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular) property on the project Java plugin to automatically set the module path:

```
subprojects {
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin).configureEach {
        java {
            modularity.inferModulePath = true
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this one with Gradle 6.6.1, and the compile is working, but ServiceLoader functionality is NOT working without the META-INF stuff. Hence it must be still using classpath I assume.

Comment: also this will not put a non-modular jar (name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.32.3.2') to the module-path, making it an automatic module (which was working in my netbeans ant project before) => it is not the same as putting everthing to the module path

Comment: @MartinMeeser: Good that you're giving information about limitations. I don't know any details about this solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

First please note: I am on Gradle 6.6.1 with Java 15.

This is what I have observed:

1. in order to make the compile work, every project needs:

   ```
   java {
       modularity.inferModulePath = true
   }
   ```
2. this can be turned on at root `build.gradle` via

   ```
    subprojects {
        apply plugin: "java"
        java {
            modularity.inferModulePath = true
        }
    }
   ```
3. in order to use modulepath with `gradle run` (ServiceLoader working WITHOUT META-INF, reflection restrictions ...) you have to use following application section:

   ```
   application {
        mainModule = 'org.gradle.sample.app' // name defined in module-info.java
        mainClass = 'org.gradle.sample.Main'
        // DO NOT USE   mainClassName = 'org.gradle.sample.Main'
   }
   ```

Took me quite some time to put all together from several Gradle pages ---
but it is all [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_modular).

Note:

This will not but non-modular jars to the module-path.