# Add a Java Module jar as a dependency into a Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

This is my multi-project Gradle setup:

```
.
└── gradle-module-project1
    ├── application
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── gradlew
    ├── list
    ├── settings.gradle.kts
    └── utilities
```

`application`, `utilties` and `list` are projects, and inside each one there is a Java Module.

That is, each project has its own `src/main/java/module-info.java` file and `build.gradle.kts` file.

I also have another Gradle project which has a similar project structure, example:

```
.
└── gradle-module-project2
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── gradlew
    ├── settings.gradle.kts
    └── superapi
```

`superapi` is a Java Module and exposes a package.

I have built `superapi` as a `.jar`, using `./gradlew build`

Now I'm trying to add `superapi.jar` as a dependency to `gradle-module-project1`, so that `gradle-module-project1` can consume the exported public classes from the `superapi` module.

In IntelliJ, I have done:

`Project Structure` -> `Modules` -> `Dependencies` -> `Add` -> `Jars/Directory`

Selected the created jar and can see the jar in the `External Libraries` of my project.

But when I try to add:

```
requires com.test.modules.superapi;
```

to the `module-info.java` for `application`, I get this error:

```
Module is not in dependencies: com.test.modules.superapi
```

The suggested fix is to: `Add library: 'superapi.jar!' to classpath` but that does nothing.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Kindly check out my answer to get it done completely (gradle build AND gradle run with ServiceLoader etc..) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354261/973184)

Answer (score 0):

At the end you have 2 projects and have to make a relation between the 2

add `dependency` in gradle-module-project1 either as `nexus repo g:a:v` or `local code include, project()`