# Why isn't Gradle using the module-info.class of an MRJAR?

Tags: java, gradle, picocli

I am currently using picocli to create a command-line application. However, Gradle refuses to build it with the following error message.

```
{project path}\src\main\java\module-info.java:2: error: module not found: info.picocli
    requires info.picocli;
```

Here's my Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    implementation 'info.picocli:picocli:4.6.1'
}
```

Picocli is hosted as an MRJAR with a `module-info.class` under `META-INF\versions\9`, but it seems that Gradle isn't using the file. Why is this?

Comment: you followed [this](https://picocli.info/#_java_9_jpms_modules)?

Comment: I have configured my `module-info.java` correctly, but Gradle can't find the module-info of picocli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63575805/1446916), you may need to set the [`inferModulePath`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular) property on the project Java plugin.