# Java Modules, Gradle project - Problems with external libraries

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, saxon, java-module

I have a multi module project in `IntelliJ`, a java library project, using `Gradle` with quite old versions of libraries
I must say, and now switching to `Java 11` (using right now OpenJDK 11.0.2 from https://jdk.java.net/archive/).

I want to modularize that library project, adding to all modules a `module-info.java`.
I keep getting an error in one of the modules with one of the dependencies, `Saxon-HE`.

I isolated that module in a separate project (using `Gradle 7.6`), and modified the `build.gradle` dependencies step by step as `IntelliJ` discovered
import errors, while using the latest versions of the dependencies.

The `build.gradle` of the project looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The `build.gradle` of the module looks like this up to the point with the error with `Saxon-HE`.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
    implementation group: 'org.jdom', name: 'jdom2', version: '2.0.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '2.0.6'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.10.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The `module-info.java` looks like this, I used the recommendations of `IntelliJ` so it added automatically the `requires` statements:

```
module mymodule1 {
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires okhttp3;
    requires okio;
    requires java.xml;
    requires org.jdom2;
}
```

The next import error `IntelliJ` discovers while building it results because one of my classes has the import statement:

```
import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;
```

Building the project results in the error:

```
error: package net.sf.saxon.xpath does not exist
import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;
```

Looking at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/11.4 I added to `build.gradle` of the module:

```
implementation group: 'net.sf.saxon', name: 'Saxon-HE', version: '11.4'
```

In `IntelliJ` I can see in the `Project` navigator view, in `External Libraries` that there is

```
Gradle: net.sf.saxon.Saxon-HE:11.4 
Saxon-HE-11.4.jar
```

`IntelliJ` recommends

```
Add 'requires Saxon.HE' directive to module-info.java
```

The `module-info.java` looks now like this:

```
module mymodule1 {
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires okhttp3;
    requires okio;
    requires java.xml;
    requires org.jdom2;
    requires Saxon.HE;
}
```

After that the error in the particular class using that import statement is gone, `IntelliJ` doesn't complain.

But when then building the project I get the error

```
C:\Users\ME\PROJECTS\myproject\mymodule1\src\main\java\module-info.java:9: error: module not found: Saxon.HE
        requires Saxon.HE;
                      ^
```

Removing the `requires Saxon.HE` and building the project results in the error:

```
error: package net.sf.saxon.xpath is not visible
import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;
                   ^
  (package net.sf.saxon.xpath is declared in the unnamed module, but module net.sf.saxon.xpath does not read it)
```

I find this error message weired, because it says `but module net.sf.saxon.xpath does not read it`, I would rather expect `but module mymodule1 does not read it.`

I don't know what's going wrong, other external dependencies are not problematic but `Saxon-HE` is.

Comment: I'm sorry, we haven't done any work with Java modules at Saxonica, so we can't offer any useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found here [Gradle build - add module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708213/gradle-build-add-module-path) a snippet which might solved it, but maybe only partially, so not sure if this answer can be marked as the solution.

I added to the project `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 19
    targetCompatibility = 19

    compileJava {
        doFirst {
            options.compilerArgs += [
                    '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                    '-Xmaxerrs', 1000
            ]
            classpath = files()
        }
    }
}
```

Now trying to build it (with `Gradle 7.6` and `OpenJDK 19`), it doesn't complain to not finding modules, so far at least, but now I have the next problem which I desribed here [Java Modules, Gradle, external dependencies - Modules reading from more then one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887317/java-modules-gradle-external-dependencies-modules-reading-from-more-then-one)