# Java Modules, Gradle, external dependencies - Modules reading from more then one

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, saxon, java-module

Starting with an initial problem discussed here [Java Modules, Gradle project - Problems with external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74851117/java-modules-gradle-project-problems-with-external-libraries) I now face a next problem in my project, which is based now on `Gradle 7.6`, now trying with `OpenJDK 19`.

Trying to build in `IntelliJ` with `Build > Build Project` or `Gradle > Tasks > build > build` I get the following outpu (about 350 errors):

```
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.xml.sax from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.xml.sax.helpers from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.xml.sax.ext from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.views from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.traversal from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.ranges from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.ls from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.html from both xercesImpl and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.events from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom.bootstrap from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.xpath from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.validation from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.transform from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.transform.stream from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.transform.stax from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.transform.sax from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.transform.dom from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.stream from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.parsers from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.namespace from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: the unnamed module reads package javax.xml.datatype from both java.xml and xml.apis
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.html from both xercesImpl and xml.apis
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.datatype from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.namespace from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.parsers from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.stream from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.transform from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.transform.dom from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.transform.sax from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.transform.stax from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.transform.stream from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.validation from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package javax.xml.xpath from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.bootstrap from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.events from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.ls from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.ranges from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.traversal from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.w3c.dom.views from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.xml.sax from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.xml.sax.ext from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okio reads package org.xml.sax.helpers from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.html from both xercesImpl and xml.apis
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.datatype from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.namespace from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.parsers from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.stream from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.stream.events from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.stream.util from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.transform from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.transform.dom from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.transform.sax from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.transform.stax from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.transform.stream from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.validation from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package javax.xml.xpath from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.bootstrap from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.events from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.ls from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.ranges from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.traversal from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.w3c.dom.views from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.xml.sax from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.xml.sax.ext from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module okhttp3 reads package org.xml.sax.helpers from both xml.apis and java.xml
    error: module org.apache.commons.io reads package org.w3c.dom.html from both xercesImpl and xml.apis
    error: module org.apache.commons.io reads package javax.xml from both xml.apis and java.xml
... shortened due to character limitation for posts ...
    C:\Users\ME\PROJECTS\myproject\mymodule1\src\main\java\module-info.java:1: error: module mymodule1 reads package org.w3c.dom.html from both xercesImpl and xml.apis
    module mymodule1 {
    ^
    351 errors
```

First, there seems to be an `unnamed module`, but which one is it, how to find that?

With the `Java Modules` system it is not allowed that the same package (name) is exported more then once, as I understand. Having those external dependencies, they don't care, some are not modularized anyway.

How to deal now with this problem?
I'm not the developer of the project, now I have the task to modularize the project.
One naive look tells me, do I need all those external dependencis, if I can remove the one or the other maybe the problem is gone. Doing everything with `java.xml` if possible, but that would mean to rewrite the project. But assuming for now that I need all those external dependencies, how can I solve this problem? I'm new to the Java Modules system, also not much familiar with Gradle.

Those external dependencies bring in additional transitive dependencies and conflicts arise while modules (dependencies) try to read packages which are provided in this scenario from two modules:

```
java.xml and xml.apis
xercesImpl and xml.apis
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to character limitation for posts (30000) I have to add some more information here.

`IntelliJ` didn't tell me about other problems, I found in one class this import statement

```
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent
```

which lead me to adding to `build.gradle`

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'fop', version: '2.8'
```

and adding to `module-info.java`

```
requires fop;
```

which pulled many other dependencies

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'fop', version: '2.8'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-->
com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:1.12
commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:2.0.24
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-constants:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-i18n:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-shared-resources:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:1.16
org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-core:2.8
org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-events:2.8
org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-util:2.8
org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:2.8
xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:1.3.04
```

Building it now leads to about 5200 errors, similar to the described, for example

```
error: module org.apache.commons.lang3 reads package org.apache.fop.fonts.base14 from both fop and fop.core
error: module Saxon.HE reads package org.apache.fop.render from both fop and fop.core
```